# Can Publish Power Bi Report Server to Power Bi Service?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I wonder can I publish visual that I create using **Power Bi Report Server** then publish it into
**Power Bi Service**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can publish into Power BI Service
FYI, Microsoft release new updates on Power BI Service every month, but for Report Server every 3-4 months